# Problem with my while and my array sqli request

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm php starter and i wan't to make my project. Here is my problem: i make a script which update info on my sqli server but a strange problem comes. It doesn't want to update for no reason.

My code:

```
<?php

                    $itemchoice = array(
                        'value' => array( '', "1" => $item1, "2" => $item2, "3" => $item3, "4" => $item4, "5" => $item5),
                        'name' => array('', "1" => "item1name", "2" => "item2name", "3" => "item3name", "4" => "item4name", "5" => "item5name"),
                    );

                    $nombre_actuel = 1;

                    echo '<form method="post">';
                    while ($nombre_actuel <= $nombredeligne)
                    {
                        echo '<input type="text" name="'.$itemchoice['name'][$nombre_actuel].'" value="'.$itemchoice['value'][$nombre_actuel].'">';
                        $nombre_actuel++;
                    }
                    echo '<input type="submit" name="envoyer" value="Envoyer">';
                    echo '</form>';

                    if (isset($_POST['item1name'])) {
                        $newitem1 = $_POST['item1name'];
                        $newitem1sql = 'UPDATE navbar SET valeur='.$newitem1.' WHERE item="item1" ';
                        $newitem1result = mysqli_query($db1, $newitem1sql);
                    }
```

The line

```
 $newitem1sql = 'UPDATE navbar SET valeur='.$newitem1.' WHERE item="item1" ';
```

Doesn't work for any reason

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Where do you check for errors? Why do you use completely unquoted input data?

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: if (isset($_POST['item1name'])) { ..... }  will be never executed because 'item1name' is nowhere defined/used.  May be I couldn't see it. One more point, you are trying to update a record, so it should exist in your dbase.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$newitem1sql = 'UPDATE navbar SET valeur='.$newitem1.' WHERE item="item1" ';
```

to this:

```
$newitem1sql = 'UPDATE navbar SET valeur="'.$newitem1.'" WHERE item="item1" ';
```

Note: You are open to SQL Injection attack. You should not just take the $_Post[] input and shove it in your SQL without sanitizing. Sanitize and parameterize your query.